# How to replace the tags in a XML

Tags: c#, html, xml, tags

i have a xml tag like :

`<p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Text1<span title="instruction=componentpresentation,componentId=1234,componentTemplateId=1111">CPText2CP</span></p>`

If i have to replace the tag `<span title="instruction=componentpresentation,componentId=1234,componentTemplateId=1111">CPText2CP</span>`  with

`<componentpresentation componentID="1234" templateID="1111" dcpID="dcp1111_1234" dcplocation="/wip/data/pub60/dcp/txt/dcp1111_1234.txt">Text2</componentpresentation>`

Is any possible way to acchive this, please give suggestion/changes.

**EDIT**

From the above tag can i take full `<span></span>` tag as a string with the text in between the tags.any suggestions.

Comment: Two questions. First, is the flag for what elements need to be transformed the title="instruction=..." atribute? Also, where does the dcpID/dcplocation attribute come from?

Comment: @Lunatic , yes i need to replace full <span> tag with <componentPresentation> tag keeping the text between tags as itis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
        string input = @"
            <p xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">
                Text1
                <span title=""instruction=componentpresentation,componentId=1234,componentTemplateId=1111"">
                    CPText2CP
                </span>
            </p>";


        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);
        XNamespace ns = doc.Root.Name.Namespace;

        // I don't know what filtering criteria you want to use to 
        // identify the element that you wish to replace,
        // I just searched by "componentId=1234" inside title attribute
        XElement elToReplace = doc
            .Root
            .Descendants()
            .FirstOrDefault(el => 
                el.Name == ns + "span" 
                && el.Attribute("title").Value.Contains("componentId=1234"));

        XElement newEl = new XElement(ns + "componentpresentation");

        newEl.SetAttributeValue("componentID", "1234");
        newEl.SetAttributeValue("templateID", "1111");
        newEl.SetAttributeValue("dcpID", "dcp1111_1234");
        newEl.SetAttributeValue("dcplocation", 
            "/wip/data/pub60/dcp/txt/dcp1111_1234.txt");

        elToReplace.ReplaceWith(newEl);
```

Your needs may vary but the way to go would be to create `XDocument` or `XElement`, search through it to find elements that need to be replaced and then use `ReplaceWith` to replace them. Note that you have to take namespaces into consideration, otherwise elements won't be retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Do the following:

1. [Read the File](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548) (As XML or [plain Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx))
2. Search for [the Tag](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/195928/how-do-i-read-specific-tag-in-xml-using-c) / [Sequence or a substring of it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx)
3. [Replace the Sequence with the new one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)